# "Going Back to Houston" from where?

Tags: history

Dean Martin sang of being in some city where he was broke, wet, hungry, and unknown. He sang of going back to Houston, but what city was he in? Was it a real city where he had been? I can't find anything on the historical background of this song.

I know he didn't write the song, but sometimes songs can still be personal, as with *Papa was a Rolling Stone* by the Temptations...Dennis Edward's real father apparently did pass away on the 3rd of September.

Comment: I don't have enough sources to write an answer, but it reminds me the vagrancy laws back then, when the homeless poors were banned from a place to another. In the song, the guy may have the opportunity to go back home after exile, maybe in close cities.

Answer (score 2):

As Dean Martin wasn't a songwriter, it would be unlikely it had any personal meaning for him, except in the self-contained world of the song itself.

[Houston](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Houston_(song)) was written by [Lee Hazlewood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lee_Hazlewood)

> The lyrics are from the perspective on a down on his luck drifter who
>   describes himself as "A walkin' case of the blues." The verses
>   describe his many misfortunes ("I found a dollar yesterday, but the
>   wind blew it away"), each ending with the repeated refrain "Going back
>   to Houston, Houston, Houston...". The mood lightens on the final verse
>   when the narrator reveals that despite his woes, he has a girlfriend
>   waiting for him in the titular city.